# Serving css and javascript files

Tags: node.js, express

I am beginner with node. I am trying to serve a file. The hierarchy of my project looks like

app

```
  modules
  node_modules
  public
    css
      index.css
    html
      index.html
    javascript
  routes
     main.js
```

inside main.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app     = express();
var path    = require('path')
var port    = 8080;

app.use("/styles",  express.static(path.join(__dirname + '../public/css')));
app.use("/scripts", express.static(__dirname + '../public/javascript'));

app.get('/' , function( req , res ){
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname,'../public/html/index.html'))
})
app.listen(port)
```

i want to serve a file on / route. It works fine , but css and javascripts are not loaded - it throws error in browswer console

> http://localhost:8080/css/index.css Failed to load resource: the
>   server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

What is the right way to set path to css? I have trouble to find the righ solution.

Thanks!

Comment: your static css route is called "styles", not "css"; try `http://localhost:8080/styles/index.css`

Comment: @Hamms it doesnt find the file either , why styles?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is with your path definition. When you use path.join you should pass strings to it and this method will join them with platform specific separator as a delimiter, then normalizes the resulting path.

so your styles path should be:

```
app.use("/styles",  express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'css')));
```

and your styles will serve from:

```
http://localhost:8080/styles/index.css
```

Because you are using a **virtual path prefix** (here: /styles).

If you dont mind platform specific separator, i. e. know that your server will be a unix like environment and dont need a *virtual path prefix*  then just use:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

and your styles will serve from *css* dir:

```
http://localhost:8080/css/index.css
```

Comment: The final style route won't be served from `localhost:8080/index.css` but rather `localhost:8080/css/index.css`

Comment: @Josh, make sure that you're not using relative paths within your HTML file when loading your css. `../css/index.css` won't be a valid route however, `/css/index.css` is a valid route.

Comment: @peteb, i checked just now and it serves from root: `http://localhost:8080/index.css`

Comment: @dNitro yes, that's true if you're going to make the static route `/public/css` instead of `/public`.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/4byK7Ukk this is my current code , hierarchy stays the same , i run it by node main.js , i rly do not know what would work

Comment: http://pastebin.com/ZPT6gGVD try this code. just place your *index.html* in *public* folder, then with your browser go to *http://localhost:8080* and it will serve your *index.html*

Comment: I tried everything i found on internet , nothing seems to work

Comment: @Josh If the hierarchy of your project is yet same as above, move *main.js* outside *routes* directory into root project dir, also move *index.html* outside *html* folder into *public* dir, replace content of *main.js* with [this](http://pastebin.com/ZPT6gGVD), then run `node main.js` command and surf to `http://localhost:8080` with your browser will load index.html and `http://localhost:8080/css/index.css` will load your css file.

Answer (score 1):

Because you set another routes. Change your routes to static files. Use this:

```
app.use(express.static('../public'));
```

Comment: The relative path for `../public` is unnecessary when using `__dirname` because that's precisely what `__dirname` provides. `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public');` is the correct way to use `path.join()`. The `+` is counter to the reason why you'd use `path.join()`.

Comment: @peteb you are right, it's my mistake. I've fixed it